# Spring RestController AOP custom access rules for each method

Tags: java, spring, rest, aop

I have an API class where several methods have different access rule requirements, e.g. only users in a group can access this API, or this API allows unauthenticated access.

What is the best practice to handle this in Spring?

I was hoping to use AOP to handle this with a custom annotation, but after investigating it doesn't seem possible. e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/getGroup")
@GroupMembersOnly
```

Comment: Have you read about spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working now.

The annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface GroupMembersOnly {

}
```

The part I was missing in my configuration class

```
@Aspect
public class AopConfiguration{
...
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(groupMembersOnly)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point, GroupMembersOnly groupMembersOnly) throws Throwable {

    //do something, e.g. use point.getArgs()
    //to do something with the menthod arguments

    //give control back to method
    return point.proceed();
}
}
```

Then on the method I want to intercept

```
@RequestMapping("/getGroup")
@GroupMembersOnly
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> readMembers(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
/*Add HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response arguments if you 
want to do something with them in the interceptor*/
```